# How to implement real-time face recognition and blurring to a specific person?

Tags: computer-vision

I would like to implement real-time video face anonymizer to a specific person.

While I am recording a video, I would like to blur people's face without me. When I input my face image and start to record a video, I want to see a screen that express only my face and other's face is blurred. Is it possible to implement this?

Comment: You could, but it is not trivial. I would train a classifier to generally detect faces in a video and use those as training input to train another classifier to detect specifically your face among other faces. You could then use this information to blur out everyone's face but your own.